# Bidirectional index in SQLite without duplicating text keys?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I hope to create a SQLite table that maps between unique texts and their IDs. You can efficiently look up the ID for some text, and vice-versa. Text lengths range from around 4 bytes to 1KB.

I started with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE texts (
    text TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    text_id INTEGER NOT NULL
) WITHOUT ROWID
```

this creates a [without rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table which stores the text content once, in the index. This efficiently maps texts to IDs.

To map from ID to text, I tried:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_text_id
ON texts (text_id)
```

unfortunately this new index doubles the size of the table, because it stores a separate copy of the texts. How can I avoid this separate copy?

One idea I had was to store the texts in a normal column, and index the hashes of the texts, rather than the texts themselves. However this is awkward to implement, so I was hoping for an easier way. Thanks for any help!